# Solving multilib version problems

Tags: centos, installation, yum, rpm, 32bit-64bit

I use *CentOS 6.4*

When I tried to install libgcc with `yum install libgcc.i686` I took following massages.

```
Error:  Multilib version problems found. This often means that the root
       cause is something else and multilib version checking is just
       pointing out that there is a problem. Eg.:
       
         1. You have an upgrade for libgcc which is missing some
            dependency that another package requires. Yum is trying to
            solve this by installing an older version of libgcc of the
            different architecture. If you exclude the bad architecture
            yum will tell you what the root cause is (which package
            requires what). You can try redoing the upgrade with
            --exclude libgcc.otherarch ... this should give you an error
            message showing the root cause of the problem.
       
         2. You have multiple architectures of libgcc installed, but
            yum can only see an upgrade for one of those arcitectures.
            If you don't want/need both architectures anymore then you
            can remove the one with the missing update and everything
            will work.
       
         3. You have duplicate versions of libgcc installed already.
            You can use "yum check" to get yum show these errors.
       
       ...you can also use --setopt=protected_multilib=false to remove
       this checking, however this is almost never the correct thing to
       do as something else is very likely to go wrong (often causing
       much more problems).
       
       Protected multilib versions: libgcc-4.4.7-4.el6.i686 != libgcc-4.4.7-3.el6.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles –nodigest
```

How can I install `libgcc.i686`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It seems your `libgcc.x86_64` has a different version than the `libgcc.i686` you are trying to install (`4.4.7-3` vs. `4.4.7-4`). Try to update the x86_64 lib together with the installation of the i686-lib:

```
yum install libgcc.x86_64 libgcc.i686
```

Comment: I report I can install libgcc.i686 with `yum install libgcc.x86_64 libgcc.i686`.

Answer (score 11):

I've hit this after interrupting `yum update` (during an ansible run in my case).  After reading [this thread](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=52898) I eventually fixed it with:

```
package-cleanup --cleandupes
```

Though before that I'd also tried running commands as @etagenklo suggested, and also tried:

```
yum-complete-transaction
yum-complete-transaction --cleanup-only
yum check                # report generally
package-cleanup --dupes  # report on duplicate packages in particular
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it worth to mention because it was my issues check

> /etc/yum.repos.d/*

and check if there is not used or unofficial source

Answer (score -1):

Only this command solved this problem for me:
yum -y distribution-synchronization

Answer (score -2):

How can we fix this error?

```
Error:  Multilib version problems found.
```

This often means that the root cause is something else and multilib version checking is just pointing out that there is a problem. Eg.:

1. You have an upgrade for apr which is missing some
           dependency that another package requires. Yum is trying to
           solve this by installing an older version of apr of the
           different architecture. If you exclude the bad architecture
           yum will tell you what the root cause is (which package
           requires what). You can try redoing the upgrade with
           `--exclude apr.otherarch ...` this should give you an error
           message showing the root cause of the problem.
2. You have multiple architectures of apr installed, but
           yum can only see an upgrade for one of those arcitectures.
           If you don't want/need both architectures anymore then you
           can remove the one with the missing update and everything
           will work.
3. You have duplicate versions of apr installed already.
           You can use `yum check` to get yum show these errors.

   ...you can also use `--setopt=protected_multilib=false` to remove
   this checking, however this is almost never the correct thing to
   do as something else is very likely to go wrong (often causing
   much more problems).

   ```
   Error:
   Protected multilib versions: apr-1.3.9-5.el6_2.i686 != apr-1.5.2-2.x86_64
   Protected multilib versions: apr-util-1.3.9-3.el6_0.1.i686 != apr-util-1.5.4-2.x86_64
   ```

Comment: `--setopt=protected_multilib=false` Helpful. Thanks.